# Reference string characters by index after search and offsetting index

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a string with a serial code followed by a numeric voltage at the end: "J7W237 20kV", "LABEL34 v20/35kV". I am using the following formula to determine if the voltage meets the requirements of the system. The way I am thinking to do this is use SEARCH for kV, then using the index of the result to call the 2 characters before the search result, but I'm not sure how I would index through a string like that?

```
=IF(U284=$F$275;IF(K284>0;IF(F21<SEARCH("kV";D284);"→";"");""))
```

Edit: I could do this relatively easily in VBA but just wondered if this is possibly simpler to build off some preexisting conditions

Comment: Would the voltage always be just the 2 characters in front of 'kV'? Would 'kV' always be at the end? Please can you show some more samples with expected results?

Comment: @JvdV No, kV is not always necessarily at the end but the number (20 in this case) is always preceding the kV. We could have something else like: "LABEL 45kV - Only for xyz" or "LABEL42 v16/32kV"

Comment: But....would the actual voltage always be two or possible more/less characters long?

Comment: @JvdV Currently it's only 2.. it's possible we could have a half voltage: 30,5kV but I think it's simpler to assume it's always 2. However, the value of F21 being compared can be 2 or 3 (20 or 20,5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=MAP(A1:A4,LAMBDA(x,-LOOKUP(1,-("00"&RIGHT(LEFT(x,FIND("kV",x)-1),ROW(1:99))))))
```

This works if you, just like me, have a decimal comma.

---

**Explanation:**

[image]

Comment: Cheers mate this works great; no idea HOW it works, but thanks!

Comment: I've also found that =MID(A1, FIND("kV", A1)-2, 2) to also work, is there something I am not accounting for with this?

Comment: @Alexander, that does not work with decimal comma and neither would it work with number greater or smaller then two characters. Avoid it!

Comment: With your formulas, I usually take them piece by piece to understand better (and hopefully get to use it later with that knowledge), but I'm not quite understanding how the `LOOKUP` works. The`RIGHT(LEFT...` I'm able to understand as well as needing that to get the first full number coming out of the string but I don't see how adding a "00" and making it negative would make the lookup find a 1, i.e. J7W237 20kV. It works but I don't fully understand it, could you explain that part, please? @JvdV

Comment: @Notus_Panda, does the update help?

Comment: It helps and then some! Thanks a bunch :) I got a bit confused with the documentation stating *"matches the nearest smaller value"* but I suppose they just didn't have an entry with negative numbers acting differently. Also I haven't encountered an issue yet with certain strings being read as numbers when simply multiplying by 1 but I'll keep that in mind for my next times. Thanks for the explanation (sadly can't upvote twice ^^)

Comment: @JvdV thanks for the explanation, could you also quickly explain why the ROWS(1:99) is used? I have tried moving the equation around the sheet and it still seems to want ROWS(1:LARGENUMBER), and I assume it has to do with step 4 of the update? Is it simply using these rows as calculation space or something?

Comment: If you move this formula around much, maybe change this part into `SEQUENCE(LEN(A1))`. The number 99, in combination with `ROW(1:99)` would simply give a large array of numbers ranging 1-99 @Alexander

Comment: @JvdV Yep that works perfectly. Why is it that ROW(1:99) does not behave correctly here as it is giving an array of numbers not the actual rows?